# Implementing ports/sockets in d3 graph nodes to map outputs into other nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, d3.js, visualization

I want to create a D3 Node editor like UI just using D3.

Has someone tried incorporating sockets/ports in their graph nodes before.
I have searched a lot on the web but didn't find any example which fits my need.
 I am sure someone must have tried making a flow based UI before using D3.

**Here is a reference to the [UI I am trying to create](https://github.com/Ni55aN/d3-node-editor)**

**I want to create the following graph editor with the addition of ports/sockets by just using d3 [Graph editor with ports/sockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxABN.png)**

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail? For example, in a gitter: https://gitter.im/D3-Node-Editor/Lobby

Comment: I want to create a simple graph editor similar to the one like yours with multiple inputs and outputs. Is it possible to create a similar graph editor by just using D3 and decoupling the engine and worker logic ?

Comment: @Ni55aN Here is a blocks.org reference to the type of graph creator I want to develop but with the addition of multiple input and output ports/sockets extending from each node. [Graph Creator](https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459)